# Why aren't my imports for Python working in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, importerror, python-venv

First of all, I am new to both Python as well as the world of VSCode (recently moved over from Atom). I will also say that I am using an **Early 2014 MacBook Air running macOS Catalina**. I really do love VSCode! It's amazing in many ways, but this... this is just too unclear.

Okay, **I have tried literally almost everything** and I don't understand why my imports won't work!  I have looked at the documentation on the issue on Github (I will say I may have something with the directory wrong there, referring to the docs). I have tried the `"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [],` thing. I have tried changing my (virtual) environment and, of course, setting up a new one myself. I have tried setting `"python.languageServer:"` to `Jedi` and back to `Microsoft`. I can't even find the `"python.jediEnabled: false"` comment that everybody is telling me to uncomment.

Yet, my imports are **still** *"unresolved (Microsoft language server)"* or *"not found (Terminal)"* or *"unable to be imported (Pylint)"*. It just makes me so angry and I don't understand what I've done wrong!

I've seen modules like `pygame` and `requests` work just fine on VSCode for many others (YouTube), yet mine has yet to work.

Can someone please tell me the secret that I don't apparently know? Thanks.

---

Update Post: [My Virtual Environment is using my System Python rather than my Venv's Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62857559/11842042)

Thank you for everyone who has helped (so far). I am getting a lot closer to solving this. ^-^

Comment: Have you installed  "Python extension for VS Code" from the Visual Studio Marketplace?

Comment: This might help: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial

Comment: @SanketSingh Yes I have installed the Python extension for VSCode. I also looked at the tutorial link you gave me, thank you. However I am still unable to use my imported modules. Nothing changed, unfortunately.

Comment: I will add that there is a loop in which I reload the window, and it switches to the Python extension. Then, once loaded, it gives another prompt stating that the languageServer must be set to Microsoft in order to use Intellicode. This happens every time and continues to loop if I click the `reload` button on the prompt.

Comment: Can you confirm that you have the "python.jediEnabled": "false" setting set? The toast message should only show up if you have jediEnabled set to true.

Comment: @SanketSingh Yes, I can confirm that I have this setting set. However, it is slightly faded out and giving the error, "unknown configuration setting". Here's a picture of my configuration settings (for Python) https://imgur.com/a/gG52apv.

Comment: Why do you have a `:` in your directory name?

Comment: @rioV8 I guess a forward slash (`/`) gets converted to a colon (`:`).

Comment: Have you made sure that you installed the packages that are triggering import errors into the environment you are selecting for the Python extension? For instance both pygame and requests are 3rd-party and thus do not come with Python itself.

Comment: Yes, I make my venv my source and use pip to install these packages. Pip then tells me that they _are_ installed! Yet according to VSCode and Terminal, apparently not. Would I be okay to uninstall VSCode and then reinstall it? Or could that damage files?

Comment: Just suggesting a couple of checks. Make sure you have enabled virtualenv if you are using one. VS code should automatically set the interpreter to that of virtualenv. Just see what interpreter is being used. Moreover, just run the program once. In my case with virtualenv, I had to execute the program once for intelisense to recognize venv libs. And may be reloading after execution may help.

Comment: @DeekshithAnand Okay, thank you. I will try to execute the program and then maybe reload and see what happens. Right now I'm honestly just trying to get the venv working in the first place (as in even outside of VSCode)! Checking which interpreter is being used is more complicated than just typing out "Python Interpreter," because for whatever reason it seems to change around a lot. Between using Intellisense and Pylint and between using the the system Python interpreter and the venv interpreter. I can't even select my venv interpreter, it seems! :/

Comment: @Lathryx well to select interpreter in vscode , type ctrl + shift + p(search the mac eqvivalent) ,for vscode, and then type python:select interpreter. You should see option to set interpreter. Select the venv option or whatever the name you have set. Thats it!

Comment: to activate venv, just type : source venv/bin/activate in integrated terminal., and execute your program from there. If you have renamed your virtualenv something other than venv,just replace venv in the command.

Comment: @DeekshithAnand Yes, I have done that. I know how to activate my venv and it was indeed activated. Trust me, I thought the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

They had removed "python.jediEnabled" setting instead of "python.languageServer", you can refer to [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#enhancements).

Maybe you haven't installed the package which you want to import, because you had used the wrong 'pip'. When you select the right environment, you need to activate it(Ctrl+Shift+`), otherwise, you'd use the wrong 'pip'. You can type 'pip --version' to check which 'pip' you are using. Then you can try to install the package you want to import.

Comment: So to be clear, I need to go back to my virtual environment. Then, I need to do pip3 instead of pip (what I was using) to install the packages (pygame and literally any other external module) that I want in the virtual environment that way? I have activated my venv already using the activate script included.

Comment: have you checked the pip you are using? in other words, can you find the packages in your virtual environment? Which under {environmentName}/Lib/site-packages?

Comment: Yes, I believe I am using [19.2.3](https://imgur.com/a/0QeIjMi) of pip. That link shows an image of the two folders inside of my venv.

Comment: So, can you find the packages such as 'pygame' under your virtual environment, as you said you had used the right 'pip' which under virtual environment to install the package which you want? you can try command 'pip show pygame', or 'pip install pygame', to find whether you really had installed the package.

Comment: Yes, [it is installed](https://imgur.com/a/SGn9qRs). (link to screenshot)

Comment: From the picture you give out, first, you'd better install the python3 instead of python2, second, the pygame you had installed really under the global python instead of the virtual environment. So, first, you should check 'pip --version' to identify you are using the right pip which under your virtual environment, then to install the package you need.

Comment: Now that you point it out, I wasn't using the correct interpreter. However, when attempting to switch to my venv's interpreter, it wouldn't! I click my venv interpreter and it just.. doesn't! After going back to "Select Python Interpreter" after selecting the venv, it hasn't changed from the 2.7 interpreter from before. I also used "pip list" and both "requests" and "pygame" (the two that I was trying to use) show up (globally and from the venv)!

Comment: Here's my [settings.json](https://imgur.com/a/qaarSnU), by the way.